# What is the status of US20120049410?

Tags: patentability, pair, manufacturing, us20120049410

Has the patent been issued? Has been approved for manufacturing?

In reference to the patent: [US20120049410](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120049410)

Answer (score 2):

That's a patent application, not a grant.

Usually a granted patent is identifiable on Google patents site:

- the document's `Publication type` in the blue cartouche shows `Grant` as opposed to `Application`
- the cartouche shows the corresponding `Application Number` on the following line
- the `Discuss this Application` blue button reads `Discuss this Patent` instead
- there are 2 buttons beside the top left red "Patents" link - `Application` and `Grant`, which you can use to navigate between the 2 corresponding docs

You can see these details here: [US8967989](https://www.google.com/patents/US8967989)

I got to this patent by following the [`Inventors`](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=pts&hl=en&q=ininventor:%22Carlos%20Salazar%20Altamar%22) link from the cartouche to see other patent-related work from the same author. In the doc list obtained one can quickly check the word preceeding the filing date to distinguish between grants (`Grant`) and applications (`App.`).

For the 2nd question: approval for manufacturing doesn't really have anything to do with IP protection (which is what the patent application/grant process is about).

Comment: Dan is correct that the patent application process is about getting a patent and not an approval to proceed to manufacturing.     An easy way to remember this is to think of the patent process as the grant of a toll gate to block certain paths unless you give permission (such as a license).  On the other hand, an issued patent is NOT a bulldozer that allows you to go where you want and burst through the preexisting toll gate from earlier patents.

Answer (score 0):

One useful tool is USPTO Public PAIR found at 
http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair.  Enter the publication number or application number to see the status.  For a published US application, the entire process is available for viewing or downloading including the rejections offered by the USTPO and any amendments to the claims or arguments by the applicant. In this case, the application has been rejected five times with the most recent rejection in April of 2016.

Using PAIR is the only way to know for sure that an application has been rejected and the applicant has given up the fight. You need to check the continuity tab to ensure that the applicant has not moved the fight to a new application number with the same disclosure.

Touching base with a patent attorney can let you understand the unusual events such as a patent application getting revived for unintentional abandonment or restarting from a parallel PCT application but PAIR is a great tool for those looking to do some research on their own.